# Servlet execution threw an exception - java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties.getValue

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, maven, glassfish

I have a maven web application with the following project facets enabled.

- Dynamic Web Project 3.0
- JAX-RS REst Web Services 2.0
- Java 1.7

What I am basically trying to do is expose one of our functionalities as a RESTful web service, for which, I am using Jersey packages.

When I hit the rest URL, I am getting the following exception.

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.bnym.dwf.BulkRemoveCSVEntitlements] in context with path [/bnym-dwf-rest-app] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties.getValue(Ljava/util/Map;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFilter.getMaximumCacheLimit(HttpAuthenticationFilter.java:166)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFilter.<init>(HttpAuthenticationFilter.java:130)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.authentication.HttpAuthenticationFeature.configure(HttpAuthenticationFeature.java:602)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureFeatures(CommonConfig.java:609)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureMetaProviders(CommonConfig.java:550)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.initRuntime(ClientConfig.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State.access$000(ClientConfig.java:84)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig$State$3.get(ClientConfig.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values$LazyValue.get(Values.java:275)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig.getRuntime(ClientConfig.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.getClientRuntime(ClientRequest.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:644)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:275)
    at com.activiti.extension.bean.ActivitiEntitlementsMain.getUsers(ActivitiEntitlementsMain.java:114)
    at com.activiti.extension.bean.RemoveCEEPEntitlements.bulkRemoval(RemoveCEEPEntitlements.java:47)
    at com.activiti.extension.bean.DWFCommon.bulkRemoveUsingCSV(DWFCommon.java:640)
    at com.bnym.dwf.BulkRemoveCSVEntitlements.service(BulkRemoveCSVEntitlements.java:54)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I guess this is an issue with the version of Jersey that I am using. The list of dependencies snippet from my pom.xml is as follows.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance-repackaged</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b31</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm-util</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.axiom</groupId>
        <artifactId>axiom-impl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ewh.E3</groupId>
        <artifactId>E3Client</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
        <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-locator</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>hk2-utils</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>httpcomponents-httpcore</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-alpha6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.18.1-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2.external</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-guava</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson1</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.neethi</groupId>
        <artifactId>neethi</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.hk2</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi-resource-locator</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ws.commons.schema</groupId>
        <artifactId>XmlSchema</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I was using Jersey 2.19 packages earlier but then changed to 2.13. I have tried doing maven clean and maven build as well as Eclipse IDE's clean and build project multiple times.

In jersey-client 2.13 documentation, I find the `getValue` method available under `ClientProperties` class. Can someone help me identify why the issue still occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve these kind of errors, I usually, always update the sources of all the dependencies available in the POM.

Use the below command to fetch all sources of the jar files:

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

Now go back to eclipse, use the Ctrl + Shift + T, to find the '`org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties`' file, and verify the `getValue()` method(s).

If you find the right method (with correct order of parameters), then it is a run time issue. Check your server `lib` to find any older(new) versions of that jar.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @K139! That got my issue resolved. When I did Ctrl+Shift+T, there were 3 packages in the results, all of them in Eclipse's lib folder. The newest version 2.5.1 didn't have the getValue() methods. I had to delete them and build the project again. By the way, just to learn, by server `lib`, did you mean the tomcat lib folder or the web app's WEB-INF/lib folder?

Comment: @JeevaShanmugavel both :)